# Printer Script - Trying to create groups

Tags: printing, vbscript

Instead of writing for every computer I would like to put the computers that use the same printers into a group and if any computer name is part of that group, then it gets said printers. I've tried this many different ways and can't get it to single a specified group out. It ends up adding all the printers.

```
on error resume next
DIM ComputerName, RegEntry, CPWRIT_A, CPWRIT_B, CPWRNH_A, CPWRNH_B, CPWRNH_C

`'***************_Get Computername_************************************************

RegEntry = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName\ComputerName"
ComputerName = ReadRegValue(RegEntry)

'**********************_Computer Groups_******************************************

CPWRIT_A = "CPWRIT00, CPWRIT01, CPWRIT02, CPWRIT03"
CPWRIT_B = "CPWRIT04, CPWRIT05, CPWRIT06"
CPWRNH_A = "CPWRNH01, CPWRNH02, CPWRNH03, CPWRNH04"
CPWRNH_B = "CPWRNH05, CPWRNH06, CPWRNH07, CPWRNH08"
CPWRNH_C = "CPWRNH09, CPWRNH10, CPWRNH11, CPWRNH12, CPWRNH13"


'*****************_WR Nurse Hall_*********************************************************

IF ComputerName(CPWRNH_A) THEN

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\Nurse1_WhitePaper"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\Nurse1_RX_Paper"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\cpwrnh03\DYMO_CPWRNH03"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\SAVIN_WRN"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\hpdl120\Nurse1_WhitePaper"

ELSE
END IF

IF ComputerName(CPWRNH_B) THEN

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\SAVIN_WRN"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\cpwrnh07\DYMO_CPWRNH07"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\hpdl120\SAVIN_WRN"

ELSE
END IF

IF ComputerName(CPWRNH_C) THEN

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\Nurse2_Tray1_RX"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\Nurse2_Tray2_PlainPaper"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\SAVIN_WRN"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\cdnurse_Dymo"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\hpdl120\Nurse2_Tray2_PlainPaper"

ELSE
END IF

'*****************_WR IT Dept_*********************************************************

IF ComputerName(CPWRIT_A) THEN

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\WR_IT"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\Savin_Admin"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\cpsysop01\SAVIN_AdminTray4"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\hpdl120\WR_IT"

ELSE
END IF

IF ComputerName(CPWRIT_B) THEN

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\WR_IT"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\hpdl120\Savin_Admin"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\cpsysop01\SAVIN_AdminTray4"
objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "\\hpdl120\Savin_Admin"

ELSE
END IF

'*******************************************************************************

wscript.quit

'*****************_Returns the data in the registry value_**********************

FUNCTION ReadRegValue(ByVal RegValue)
DIM WSHShell
SET WSHShell = WScript.CREATEOBJECT("WScript.Shell")
ReadRegValue = ""
ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
ReadRegValue = WSHShell.RegRead(RegValue)
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: You should use Windows Network security policies and specialised Administrative tools, as I understand you are on domain controlled network. Do not try to make house made script because you only hurt your network security this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if instr(CPWRIT_A,computername) > 0 then
```

Remove all the elses. Or change them to elseif (which is faster but it stops checking once a match is found).

```
if instr(CPWRIT_A,computername) > 0 then
    'dah dah dah
elseif instr(CPWRNH_A,computername) > 0 then
    'dah dah dah
elseif instr(CPWRIT_B,computername) > 0 then
    'dah dah dah
endif
```

Comment: PS: the reason why it adds all printers is that it errors on each of your illegal if statements. But you are hiding errors with On Error Resume Next and not seeing it. So it just goes to the next line.